# How to pass default values from codeigniter application to different website

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, redirect

**Error**

> Not able to pass the value from this application to other website.

**View**

In this view using action i have called the controller function. If the user selects Pay-Me then value 1 will be passed to controller function.

```
<form id="formMuktinath" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/booking/bookManakamana'?>">

    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 col-lg-offset-2 control-label">Payment From </label>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <select class="select form-control" name="manakamana[payment_from]">
                  <option value="1" selected>Pay-Me</option>
                  <option value="2">BIL</option>
             </select>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-offset-5">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
         </div>
     </div>

</form>
```

**Controller**

If 1 is selected then it calls payme website. Then there **redirect** function using **$data** does not pass **amt value** to payme website.

```
public function bookManakamana(){

    if ($data = $this->input->post('manakamana')) {

        $data['created_on'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        if ($data['payment_from'] == '1') {

                    $data['amt'] = '100';

            redirect('http://dev.payme.com/pay/main',$data);

        }

        if ($data['payment_from'] == '2') {
            echo 'bli';
            exit;
        }

        redirect('booking/index');

    } else {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

}
```

Comment: Dear friend every website has its own way to recieve data.It will not recieve any data just like you want. http://dev.payme.com surely has some features to recieve the data like apis,Go and do some research and find how http://dev.payme.com/pay/main accepts data. I am sure there will be some methods or apis that can help you out

Comment: @pradeep I have passed value from the view site but not able to transfer after calling controller function. 
Payme accepts the name='amt' but why not the $data['amt']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass values in link as get variable

```
www.somewebsite.com/?var='value'
```

but if you want to send variable as post you need to use curl

Comment: when i try to use curl it says unable to load the page. @abanoub metyas